# UIActionSheet's delegate released before user input

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I thinks it's best explained if I write what's happening in order:

1) `object_1` creates `object_2` like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      Object_2 *object_2 = [[Object_2 alloc] init];
      [object_2 show]
}
```

2) `object_2` creates an `UIActionSheet`, set's itself as delegate and shows it:

```
- (void) show{
     UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title"
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController.view];

}
```

3) the user interacts with the action sheet, and a message is sent to the delegate, the delegate has been released (by ARC). So the app crashes.

How can I "retain" it, so it exist when the delegate methods are called, and "release" it when the user is done with the action sheet (and the delegate methods)?

**EDIT**

Because I'm neurotic about memory management...

After some research I ended up doing this in object2:

(if you are not that into memory, guenis answer is perfectly correct)

```
@property (strong) MoreOptionsListController *selfPointerWhileUserInteractsWithTheMenu;
```

then

```
- (void) show {
    _selfPointerWhileUserInteractsWithTheMenu = self;
    ...
}   

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    _selfPointerWhileUserInteractsWithTheMenu = nil;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `<UIActionSheetDelegate>` in your header file?

Comment: Without luck, but, yes, Kraken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
//Object1.h 
//Add a property in header
@property (nonatomic, strong) Object2 *actionSheetDelegate;

//Object1.m
//Use the property instead to retain the object
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      self.actionSheetDelegate = [[Object_2 alloc] init];
      [self.actionSheetDelegate show]
}
```

EDIT:

There is also an alternative way which I use a lot for uialertviews. It is to handle delegate methods with blocks. Action sheets are pretty close to alertviews in a sense, so you can use something like in this tutorial:

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/block-based-action-sheet/

Comment: Thanks guenis, I love second option. First option works well, maybe add delegation to release object2 when it's done with the action sheet (sounds like kind of unnecessary tough).